# MongoDB query fetch with without unwanted data using NestJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f244a0c9b20935b3bdc2cd9"
    },
    "user": {
        "rid": "5f12ba968ca0084ee7f7ea9b",
        "name": "",
        "phone": “0123456789”
    },
    "clazz": “Test”,
    "enrolment_history": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f245e2f1906715c9e52d675"
        },
        "start_from": {
            "$date": "2020-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "$date": "2020-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "enrollment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "payment_method": "Free",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "clazz_transaction": "5f3e74f8d26e962003103c11",
        "month": "2020-6"
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f3e790c1e3c741f9eb6e53b"
        },
        "start_from": {
            "$date": "2020-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "$date": "2020-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "enrollment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "payment_method": "Free",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "clazz_transaction": "5f3e790c1e3c741f9eb6e53a",
        "month": "2020-7"
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f5763bfc2464554c15a2b28"
        },
        "start_from": {
            "$date": "2020-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "$date": "2020-09-30T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "enrollment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-09-08T10:58:07.333Z"
        },
        "payment_method": "Free",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "clazz_transaction": "5f5763bfc2464554c15a2b27",
        "month": "2020-8"
    }
}
```

I have that kind of document list, so i need to fetch this document using below filters

```
{"phone":"0123456789","enrolment_history.month":"2020-6"}
```

Output =>
(remove other data inside of enrolment_history array)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f244a0c9b20935b3bdc2cd9"
    },
    "user": {
        "rid": "5f12ba968ca0084ee7f7ea9b",
        "name": "",
        "phone": “0123456789”
    },
    "clazz": “Test”,
    "enrolment_history": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f245e2f1906715c9e52d675"
        },
        "start_from": {
            "$date": "2020-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "$date": "2020-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "enrollment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "payment_method": "Free",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "clazz_transaction": "5f3e74f8d26e962003103c11",
        "month": "2020-6"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` method,

- `$match` filter documents as per your conditions
- `$set` to get filtered using `$filter`

```
ModelName.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user.phone": "0123456789",
      "enrolment_history.month": "2020-6"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "enrolment_history": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$enrolment_history",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.month", "2020-6"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZK2rZ2muyFR)